# Does the law require sheetrock on interior walls in a house?

Tags: drywall

I'm working as a contractor for a guy. He wants to cut corners on houses he is going to rent. He has a house that had a severe roof leak. There is extreme damage to several rooms. He dosen't want to pay the money to demo and rebuild with rock tape mud texture etc. He wants me to tear out then put up paneling. Is that legal? If not or even if yes can you direct me somewhere I can look up the codes?

Comment: Various things come into play, it's mostly about flame spread and fire rating. I can't imagine why you'd be texturing a slumlord drywall job - it does not need to be pretty to meet the fire codes, and I'd not even consider texture for a "high end" job, actually. Your location will matter.

Comment: You're a contractor, and you don't know where to look up building codes?

Comment: Sheetrock is cheap. If he doesn't want to pay for the labor of proper installation, just put up the sheetrock sans tape/mud and put the panelling over it.

Comment: There are probably a million houses out there with paneling and no sheetrock, but what matters is what your local inspector requires.

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

What law does your area follow?  The building inspector can tell you.  Then you can look that up.

No inspector? Then likely no codes to follow.  Then call the fire dept - as rental housing, they may have you follow a different standard than a homeowner might be required and you'll likely need Sheetrock or similar for fire resistance.